# Create UML Diagram from C# Project

Tags: c#, uml

I am currently working with a big Library that I did not write myself, there are close to no comments at all and there is no API. Therefore I thought it would be helpful if I could parse the whole project to a UML Diagram, to get a better overview of how it is structured. 
My Questions are:

1. Is there a way to automatically generate a UML Diagram from a C# project (not just one class)?
2. Can you give me any Tips on how to get a good overview of the Library fast?

Comment: There are many tools that reverse engineer C# to a UML model, but that is off-topic here.

Comment: Resharper, Show type dependency diagram.

Comment: Visual studio support for generating class and sequence diagram https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2014/08/11/working-with-class-diagrams-let-visual-studio-2013-do-the-work/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Visual Studio can produce a Class Diagram - its a pop-up menu option if you right click the project in Solution Explorer (right click project - View - Class Diagram.
It will give you a static view of the classes and when expanded which ones that they rely on.
There's also the Object Browser (under the View Menu).

Both options will probably give you information overkill.

Be aware that the Object Browser will also show you those libraries that your library code relies on, but you can at least change it to only show items with public access rights.

Installation: You have to add it separately to VisualStudio through the VisualStudio  installer. It's called "Class Designer" in it.

Comment: Does it only work in VS Pro?

Comment: When I answered this question I wouldn't have been using VS Pro, probably VS2017 Community edition. The object explorer is still there in VS2019 Community but I don't think that the Class Diagram creation is anymore

Comment: Thanks, since then I figured we need to add it separately to VS through the VS installer. It's called "Class Designer" in it.